# Как сделать нужную мне выборку из результата вложенного запроса mysql

Tags: mysql

Есть такой запрос

```
select ANY_VALUE(books_id) as id, ANY_VALUE(books.title) as books, GROUP_CONCAT(authors.author) as author, ANY_VALUE(books.year_of_publishing) as year 
from authors_books 
inner join books on authors_books.books_id = books.id 
inner join authors on authors_books.authors_id = authors.id 
where authors_books.authors_id 
in (select authors_id from authors_books where books_id in 
(select books_id from authors_books where authors_id = '5') group by authors_id) 
group by title order by id asc
```

Выводит он следующее

[image: Что выводит сейчас]

А я хочу чтобы в выводе не было книги где автор только Шекспир(то есть у которой на картинке id 3)

В этой строке authors_id = '5' 5 это id автора weed

Логика моего запроса: самым глубоким по вложенности селектом выбираем все книги связанные с автором weed, далее выбираем всех авторов связанных с этими книгами, дальше присоединяем таблицы книги и авторы где `authors_books.authors_id = 5 
или 6`(то что нам вернулось из вложенных селектов). Группируем по названию книг.

Подозреваю, что в этой логике есть серьёзные просчеты, но не могу понять, что я делаю не так.

Comment: вы объясните лучше, не то что вы хотите исключить, а что хотите выбрать. Книги где `5` является автором или соавтором? дак это `where book_id in (select distinct book_id ... where author_id = 5)` или вместо `in` заменить на самоджойн

Comment: Ваш ответ как раз то, что мне было нужно